# Using schema and table arguments in Pandas read_sql parameters

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I want to run the query `select count(?) from ?.?;` using pandas' `read_sql()` method with the parameters `select count(<column_name>) from <schema_name>.<table_name>;`.

I get the error `ValueError: ('Could not connect to db.', DatabaseError('Execution failed on sql \'select count(?) from ?.?;\': (\'42601\', \'[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2";\\nError while preparing parameters (1) (SQLExecDirectW)\')'))`.

The code I have is just like you'd expect:

```
pd.read_sql('''select count(?) from ?.?;''', conn, params=[column_name, schema_name, table_name)
```

The actual values I am providing are: `column_name`=`record_id`, `schema_name`=`c_admin`, `table_name`=`backup_table`.

I'm using pyodbc to generate a connection and postgresql is the db I am using.

Answer (score 0):

`Pyodbc` doesn't support parameterizing SQL identifiers like schemas and tables. The library `psycopg2` will allow you to create SQL strings dynamically with these types of identifiers. By following these docs on the [psycopg2 site](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html), you can do the following:

```
from psycopg2 import connect, sql

conn = connect("dbname=DBNAME user=USER password=PASSWORD host=HOST port=PORT")

sql_string = """
    select
        count( {column} ) as not_null_count
    from
        {schema}.{table}
    ;
"""

query = sql.SQL(sql_string).format(
    column=sql.Identifier('record_id'),
    schema=sql.Identifier('c_admin'),
    table=sql.Identifier('backup_table'),
)

df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```